# Debugging tactic -- how to know which process is attempting to modify a file?

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a strange bug where one of the many development tools I'm using is issuing a `git reset HEAD` in my project, causing me to lose all my work. I'm able to confirm this by checking the git reflog.

I have been trying to use the process of elimination to find which of the tools is the culprit, but that's very time consuming.

I'm wondering if there is a way to intercept all writes to `.git` directory instead, to see what process is interacting with it. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use inotify tools to watch the directory. Then check `lsof` with the result. Now the question is, what events you want - adapt accordingly, check `man inotifywait` for more event options. I decided for writing to a file and creating one:

```
 inotifywait -m -r -e modify -e create --format %w%f ~/.git  | 
 while read file ; do
    lsof ${file} 2>/dev/null
 done
```

Now if one e.g. runs `dd if=/dev/random of=/home/user/.git/test bs=1M count=10`, you will see who did it.

Comment: I'll second `lsof` as a useful tool.  Unfortunately, `inotifywait` doesn't appear to be a default package in Ubuntu, which is on the server I'm using... and without root privileges, it's hassle to get installed.  Nonetheless, nice answer!